# DBにレコードが追加されたか確認する手段はありますか？(PDO,MySql)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

下記コードを書いたphp.pdoというファイルを作り、localhost/php.pdoでアクセスすると「接続しました」とだけ表示されます。phpmyadminのデータベース‘personal’のテーブル‘friend’にデータを挿入したいのですが、**DBにレコードが追加されたか確認する手段はありますか？** ご回答のほど宜しくお願います。

```
<?php
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
    define('DB_NAME', 'personal');

    // エラー表示設定:通知系以外全て表示    
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

    try {

        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:'.DB_NAME.';'.DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        print('接続しました。');

          //SQL文を作る(新規レコード追加)
      $db -> exec("insert into friend (name, price, place) 
                                        values ('フライドチキン',100,'渋谷')");

         //プリペアドステートメントを作る
       $stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);
       //SQL文を実行
       $stm->execute();

          }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        print('ERROR:'.$e->getMessage());
        exit;
    } ?>
```

Comment: [PDOでmysqlと接続できてるか確認したい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/46871/13199)等と同じ趣旨の質問に見えますがどうでしょうか。基本的に質問の趣旨が変わらないのであれば、新しい質問を投稿するのではなく、元の質問を編集して情報を追加するなりすべきです。（編集を開始するには、投稿本文下部の「編集」をクリックしてください。）

Comment: ”$db”　というのが何の定義もされていないのに使われていますから、「$db -> exec」のところで例外が発生していると思われます。　catchで"PDOException"しか対処していないので、「$db -> exec」で発生した例外が見逃されているのだと思います。　すべての例外に対処できるように(例外の内容を表示するように)catch節を修正すれば、何の例外が発生したのかが判るようになります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DBにレコードが追加されたか確認する手段はありますか？

insert文の実行結果は、　`'$dbh -> exec'`の返り値(失敗: FALSE を返します。)を見て追加されたか判断するすると良いでしょう。
以下　単純な動作サンプルです。

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=personal', 'root', 'root');
$ret = $dbh -> exec("insert into friend (name, price, place) values ('フライドチキン',100,'渋谷')");
```